# How do I get the absolute URL of a page?

Tags: magnolia

I can get the relative URL of a page by using the [`cmsfn.link` templating function](https://documentation.magnolia-cms.com/display/DOCS61/cmsfn#cmsfn-Createlinktoanode). For example:

```
cmsfn.link(content)
[# -- Returns /example-com/example-page-slug.html --]
```

How do I get the absolute URL of a page? For example:

```
https://example.com/example-page-slug.html
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ideally, you would be able to call `LinkUtil.createExternalLink(content)`, unfortunately this method is not directly exposed to templates (Why????).

Alternative to what you are using is

```
[#assign domain = (state.originalBrowserURL?keep_before('?')?remove_ending(state.originalBrowserURI))!'']
```

Difference to reading domain over site is that it gives you domain currently used in the browser by user so it will work on author instance just fine even if you have site domains configured there to point to public instances or when you are temporarily running configuration on your localhost and so on.

Answer (score 1):

Use the [`sitefn` templating function](https://documentation.magnolia-cms.com/display/DOCS62/sitefn) to get the domain and combine it with `cmsfn.link`. For example:

```
[#assign site = sitefn.site(content)]
[#assign relativeURL = cmsfn.link(content)?remove_beginning("/" + site.name)]
[#assign domain = site.domains[0].name]

https://${domain + relativeURL}
```

Answer (score 1):

Check out the magic of `state` in [Rendering Context Objects — Magnolia 6.2](https://documentation.magnolia-cms.com/display/DOCS62/Rendering+context+objects).

```
[#-- Get / assign your path --]
[#assign path = state.originalURI]

[#-- Put it all together --]
[#assign absoluteUrl = 'https://example.com' + path]


[#-- Render it --]
${absoluteUrl}
```

If you don't like "hard coding" the protocol or domain, try grabbing them from the Site Definition or Magnolia Config. Although, how to set and retrieve those properties varies. Good luck.